# How can I get Rename and Delete on the right click context menu when right clicking a file in OPEN EDITORS

Tags: visual-studio-code

At the top of the `Explorer` is a view labeled `OPEN EDITORS`.

[image]

If I right click a file in `OPEN EDITORS`, I do not see an option to **Rename** or **Delete**. How can I get **Rename** and **Delete** on the right click context menu when right clicking a file in `OPEN EDITORS`?

Comment: you have to do that in the File/Workspace View, below `OPEN EDITORS`

Comment: I know, but I mainly work in OPEN EDITORS. I need an option to rename and delete file from OPEN EDITORS.

Comment: thanks for the answer, @rioV8.

i think it's wack that we can't rename a file from....where we would most obviously want to rename a file from. i cant imagine why this would only be available in some other place. but, eh.